# find out if the indexes of a grouped data frame match a column of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, indexing

I have a grouped data frame named `df_grouped` where `AF` & `Local` are the indexes. I would like to assert whether the indexes in `df_grouped` are equal to a column from another dataframe `df[A]`.

This is an example of my code

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Number': [5678, 2934],
        'Age': [93, 88],}
df_grouped= pd.DataFrame(data, index=["AF","Local"])

data2 = {"A":["AF","Local"],
        "Location":["US","China"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I tried this but it does not work:

```
assert df["A"].isin(df_grouped.index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use assert for pandas series you can use [`assert_series_equal`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_series_equal.html) which checks that left and right Series are equal.

```
from pandas import testing as tm
tm.assert_series_equal(df["A"], df_grouped.index.to_series(index=df["A"].index, name= df["A"].name))
```

which will give you error if series values are different.

`AssertionError: Series.index are different`

Comment: Hi @Himanshuman, it worked but the order is messed up, is there an option to ignore the order of the indexes during the assertion ?

Comment: There is an argument `check_index=False`

Comment: Or if you really want to ignore index you can use `np.array_equal(d1.values,d2.values)`